# What's exact offset degree dividing localizer and LDA?

Tags: navaids, localizer

When a localizer is offset at an angle with the runway track, it functions as a "Localizer Directional Aid or LDA." What's the exact offset degree dividing them? Any offset degree greater than 0 makes a localizer an LDA? I've checked various sources including AIM, but none of them gives me a definite answer.

Comment: That confuses me more. I guess FAA and ICAO simply have different standards for this

Comment: Here's an [approach](http://155.178.201.160/d-tpp/1708/00375LDAD28R.PDF) in KSFO. It's only 3 degrees offset but an LDA approach

Comment: @mins I think you have the right answer, at least for the FAA standards. Thanks!

Comment: @mins -- write it up and I'll give you an upvote :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The maximum angular offset for a LOC is 3° for FAA and 5° for ICAO. Everything else is named either LDA (FAA) or IGS (ICAO).

- In ICAO wording, any ILS which doesn't meet all ILS requirements is an *instrument guidance system* (IGS).
- Localizer type directional aid (LDA) is a designation used by FAA.

*Guidance /aid* refers to the fact that this system is not a precision approach, only an assistance for for the approach.

The most infamous IGS (at least for sim users) is probably the one used at [Kai Tak RWY 13](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_x0J6dTpwVCQ/TOQ0PvIH-oI/AAAAAAAAAUg/GK8kBUnJ5_g/s1600/4242276962_8b3927bace_o.jpg) until the airport was decommissioned. Current ones include [Sion LSGS RWY 25](https://www.sion-qualification.ch/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/lsgs-AD2-1-2.pdf) which terminates before the runway (see also [Washington KDCA RWY 19](http://fr.flightaware.com/resources/airport/DCA/IAP/LDA+Y+RWY+19/pdf) as commented by @Gerry), [Innsbruck LOWI](http://www.737flightsimulator.co.uk/intac/LOWI.pdf) with a 5° offset localizer or [Lugano LSGS](http://www.lugano-qualification.ch/files/lsza_aip_0813.pdf) RWY 01 for its 6.6° glideslope.

Many of those non-standard approaches are required to access an aerodrome at the bottom of a valley. All require special training and certification before a pilot is authorized to use them.

---

- ICAO defines approach characteristics in [Doc 8168](http://www.ohio.edu/people/uijtdeha/volume-2---construction-of.pdf) Procedures for Air Navigation Services (PANS-OPS), volume II: Construction of Visual and Instrument Flight Procedures. [According to SKYbrary](http://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/Circling_Approach_-_difference_between_ICAO_PANS-OPS_and_US_TERPS#Comparison_between_ICAO_PANS-OPS_and_US_TERPS) (Eurocontrol) "*PANS-OPS procedures are the international standard and are used throughout Europe and in many other countries world-wide*".
- FAA equivalent are the United States Standard for Terminal Instrument Procedures (TERPS, [Order 8260.3](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/FAA_Order_8260.3C.pdf)). According to the same source: TERPS are used by "*USA and certain other countries. These include Canada, Korea, Saudi Arabia and Taiwan*".

---

**ICAO PANS-OPS**

Final approach segment:

> (5.2.1) When runway aligned track guidance is not possible it may be
>   offset up to 5 degrees without OCA/H penalty (see 5.4.3.1, “Aligned
>   straight-in approach”). Beyond these limits (or where other
>   requirements cannot be met) a circling approach shall be used.

ILS Cat I:

> (2.1.1) The localizer course line shall intersect the runway extended
>   centre line:
>
> a) at an angle not exceeding 5°; and b) at a point where the nominal
>   glide path reaches a height of at least 55 m (180 ft) above threshold.
>   This is called intercept height.
>
> (2.1.2) The procedure shall be annotated: “localizer offset ...
>   degrees” (tenth of degrees). The general arrangement is shown in
>   Figure II-1-2-1.
>
> [image]

**FAA TERPS**

Localizer without glide path. Final Segment alignment (8-1-2):

> Localizers aligned within three degrees of the RCL are identified as 
>   localizers. If the alignment exceeds 3 degrees, they will be
>   identified as LDA facilities.

Localizer with glide path (ILS). Final segment alignment (10-2-2 a):

> Where a unique operational requirement indicates a need to offset the
>   course  from RCL, the offset must not exceed three degrees. The offset
>   course must intersect the runway centerline at a point 1100 to 1200
>   feet inside the DA point (see figure 10-2-2 ). For offset courses the
>   minimum HAT is 250 feet and the minimum RVR is 2400.
>
> [image]

For LDA with GS (10-2-2 b):

> The final course maximum offset from RCL extended is 15 degrees. The
>   final course must cross the RCL extended at least 3000 feet from LTP,
>   but no more than 5200 feet from LTP.

Comment: KDCA Rwy 19 has two LDA approaches.  LDA Y RWY 19 has an LDA offset of 37.49 deg and a glide slope.  The GS is unusable below 1100' which leaves the DA at 1100' and 3.4 NM from the threshold.  LDA Z RWY 19 has an LDA offset of 39.99 deg with no GS. It has an MDA of 720' for the S-LDA approach with a MAP 0.8 NM (DME 1.6) from the threshold. This would appear to the extreme case for an LDA approach.

Comment: @Gerry -- never mind that one of the LDAs (the one that *was* called the ROSSLYN LDA RWY 19 in a previous life, I believe) is actually on top of a building in DC, not at the airport!

Comment: @UnrecognizedFallingObject  The localizer for the LDA Z RWY 19 is across the Potomac at Joint Base Anacostia-Bolling.

Comment: @Gerry -- a-ha, guess I'll have to give finding the antenna on Google Maps another shot then xD