# Telluride (KTEX): Why is the localizer antenna located where the glideslope should be?

Tags: airport-design, localizer

[Telluride](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IP_2ASzpPqA) (KTEX) in Colorado, USA:

[image]
<sup>[Source](https://www.pilotsofamerica.com/community/threads/flying-into-telluride-tips.85384/)</sup>

As visible, the [localizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrument_landing_system_localizer) antenna for RWY 09 is located where the [glideslope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrument_landing_system_glide_path) antenna is usually found, abeam the touch down zone. The localizer is normally seen at the end of the runway, aligned with the runway center line.

- Why was the localizer moved close to the TDZ at Telluride airport?
- What is the practical impact for the pilot to have the localizer beam distant from landing path?

Comment: @RalphJ -- it's neither -- it's a straight-up LOC.  I wonder what'd happen if you added a GS to this config, though...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The localizer for runway 09 is offset by 3°, almost certainly because of terrain. That would be a typical reason for a non-standard installation.

The [approach plate for the LOC RWY 09 approach](https://skyvector.com/files/tpp/1712/pdf/06920L9.PDF) notes the offset (more than 3° and [it would be an LDA approach](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/42705/62)):

[image]

The final approach course for the LOC 09 is 093°, whereas for the two RNAV (GPS) approaches it's 096°, which is also the current magnetic heading of the runway. The [Chart Supplement](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/dafd/search/results/?cycle=1711&ident=KTEX&navaid=) has various notes indicating that terrain is an issue (and RWY 09 has a displaced threshold) so everything indicates that the localizer is offset slightly for that reason, presumably to avoid signal interference.

As for practical issues for pilots, correcting for a 3° offset shouldn't be a problem. A bigger consideration seems to be that the MDA on the LOC 09 approach is more than 2000' AGL so if the pilot breaks out late he'll very likely have to circle to land.

Comment: I've flown in here quite a few times, and it is absolutely offset due to terrain to the North, which is quite impressive!  There is also a cliff just prior to the runway threshold while on approach to runway 9, so don't land short.